# Twitter bootstrap: carousel control not vertically aligning correctly in all responsive views

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

My carousel controls look fine at 940px, but when I resize the browser to tablet or mobile views the controls are not aligned in vertically in the center.

View example [here](http://sacgamehub.com/).

Comment: **Side note**: a diff between the **bootstrap.css** coming from your server and the official one shows differences.  I would recommend in your case getting a fresh official copy and making sure to keep your overrides in your **styles.css**.  Speaking of your **styles.css** you have many reduplicated rules in there that should be cleaned out.

Answer (score 3):

In **styles.css** you have the rule:

```css
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The `height: 100%` is the violating code, and should be removed.  In fact, all the other rules you have there are duplicates of rules already present in **bootstrap.css**, so you *should* just get rid of all of it.